# Stream - print values before and after sort

Tags: string, sorting, java-8, java-stream

I am beginner of `Java 8` and today I just started with my very first `lambda` expression. I have a `String` array, wanna print values before and after sort. Below is my code, right now it gives `stream has already operated upon or closed` exception because I have used the `forEach` twice on `friendsStream`.

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
class FirstLambda {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        String [] friends = new String [] {"C","A","B","D"};

        Stream<String> friendsStream = Stream.of(friends);

        System.out.println("My Friends:-");
        printStream(friendsStream);

        System.out.println("My Friends (after sort):- ");
        Stream<String> sortedFriends = friendsStream.sorted((String m,String n) -> m.compareTo(n));
        printStream(sortedFriends);
    }

    private static void printStream(Stream<String> stream) {
        stream.forEach(s->System.out.println(s));
    }
}
```

My question is, what is the simplest or best way to solve my problem? That is print the string values before and after sort using `java 8` `Stream` (ie. lambda)

Comment: You can just use `friendsStream.sorted()` with no lambda to sort, because by default it will use that `compareTo` method. The solution is to use two different `Stream` objects.

Comment: I Agree. But, how do I print values before sort and after sort ?

Comment: @Sridhar *The solution is to use two different Stream objects.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you ask “what is the simplest or best way to solve my problem?”, then the answer is that you don’t need a Stream at all:

```
String[] friends = {"C", "A", "B", "D"};
System.out.println("My Friends: "+Arrays.toString(friends));
Arrays.sort(friends);
System.out.println("My Friends (after sort): "+Arrays.toString(friends));
```

Note that the same works with the Collection API:

```
List<String> friends = Arrays.asList("C", "A", "B", "D");
System.out.println("My Friends: "+friends);
friends.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
System.out.println("My Friends (after sort): "+friends);
```

If you want to bring in the Stream API, there are several approaches. The simplest:

```
String[] friends = {"C", "A", "B", "D"};
System.out.println("My Friends: ");
Arrays.stream(friends).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
System.out.println("My Friends (after sort): ");
Arrays.stream(friends).sorted().forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Note that `Arrays.stream` is the preferred way to construct a stream for an *existing array*, which will also work for `int[]`, `long[]` and `double[]`, whereas `Stream.of` is the canonical way of constructing a stream with given arguments, using the *varargs* feature, e.g. `Stream.of("C", "A", "B", "D")`.

We can use this for the next variant, using a single stream and peeking into the stream:

```
Stream.of("C", "A", "B", "D")
      .peek(System.out::println)
      .sorted()
      .forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

But note that `peek` is mainly for debugging the Stream processing as it allows seeing elements as they are processed.

But if you want to understand the Stream API, you should avoid using `forEach` or `forEachOrdered`, as all operations incorporating `forEach`/`forEachOrdered` end up being only an alternative way of writing a loop and more than often, a more complicated way.

Considering that the actual intended operation is to compose a string to print, a more sophisticated usage would be:

```
String[] friends = {"C", "A", "B", "D"};
System.out.println("My Friends: "
    +Arrays.stream(friends).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println("My Friends (after sort): "
    +Arrays.stream(friends).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

Comment: I like that single stream with peeking.. awesome

Comment: But note, as said, that this is mainly for finding out, how elements are processed, which is good to learn (so you see that `sort` forces processing of all source elements, before the terminal `forEachOrdered` processes them, which is not how most other intermediate operations work, e.g., try with `filter` instead of `sort`), and it’s good for debugging, but not the right solution for production code.

Comment: The thing I don't like about using `Collectors.joining`, is that it creates a single potentially huge string in memory before printing. So it's not as efficient as it could be with printing straight to `System.out`.

Comment: And the difference with using `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` is, of course, that the backing array/collection is mutated in the process, while it isn't with the stream.

Comment: @4castle: it’s always a trade-off between memory consumption and number of I/O operations, but printing elements is a typical example code while almost never appearing in real life code. Regarding, `Arrays.sort`/`Collections.sort` vs. `Stream.sort`, of course, you can clone the array if you really need the original later-on, that’s what happens behind the scenes of `Stream.sort` anyway…

Answer (score 2):

Each `Stream` can only have one terminal operation. [`forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-) is a terminal operation, so you will have to use a separate `Stream` object every time you want to use `printStream`.

Use one `Stream` before the sort, and another `Stream` after the sort:

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FirstLambda {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        String[] friends = new String[] {"C","A","B","D"};

        System.out.println("My Friends:-");
        printStream(Arrays.stream(friends));

        System.out.println("My Friends (after sort):- ");
        printStream(Arrays.stream(friends).sorted());
    }

    private static void printStream(Stream<?> stream) {
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/Qvoa8u)

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest way to do it with `streams`. Here is an example of sorting array of ints with output results before and after sorting.

```
IntStream numbers = new Random().ints(10, 0, 20);
    numbers.boxed()
            .peek(n -> System.out.print(n+","))
            .sorted()
            .forEach(n -> System.out.print(n+"|"));
```